# Powershell Array for Path

Tags: powershell, powershell-v3.0, powershell-v4.0, powershell-v5.0

We are trying to break the following Path from the text file, the path is dynamic in length, i.e, it can be `ABC\DSD\AAR\ARE` or `ABC\DSD`.

So we need a solution to break down the path as per the following example.

```
ABC\DSD\AAR
```

to

```
ABC$
ABC\\DSD$
ABC\\DSD\\AAR\\*
```

The Last element should end with `\\*`. However all parent elements will end with `$` and it should increment until last element is reached and write to file via Out-File module.

May we ask your help to solve this problem through Powershell?

Thank you,

Rokr1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following would do

```
$x = ""; ("ABC\DSD\AAR" -split '\\' | % {$x = "$($x)$($_)\"; $x -replace '\\$', '$'}) -join " " -replace '\$$', '\*'
```

or a bit more longwinded

```
$x = ""
("ABC\DSD\AAR" -split '\\' | 
    Foreach-Object  {
        $x = "$($x)$($_)\"
        $x -replace '\\$', '$'
    }
) -join " " -replace '\$$', '\*'
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lieven,

That works, however there are list of paths like

$i = @('ABC\DSD\AAR','ABC\ZRS\ASK','KAS\DSR\BBX')

also the output should be;
ABC$ #Line 1
ABC\\DSD$ #Line 2
ABC\\DSD\\AAR\\* #Line 3

All in new line

Comment: @rokr1 - `$x="";$x=("ABC\DSD\AAR" -split '\\' | % {$x = "$($x)$($_)";"$($x)$";$x = "$($x)\\"});$x[-1]=$x[-1] -replace '\$$', '\\*';$x`

Comment: Okay Adding Function works

[array]$i = @('abc\abd\ssd','add\frd\sdr')
function getdata($s){
$x = ""
(($s -split '\\' | % {$x = "`n$($x)$($_)\"; $x -replace '\\$', '$'}) -join " " -replace '\$$', '\*') -replace '\\', '\\';
}
foreach($s in $i ){
getdata($s)
}